# jQuery Selectric (select replacement) validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-selectric

I am using Selectric (http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/) in my webdesign.

I Want to force user to choose option from select (different from default one) and validate this event by jQuery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Problem is that Selectric builds select options as `<li>` elements (hides HTML select) so I can't validate it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Problem is that Selectric builds select options as `<li>` elements (hides HTML select) so I can't validate it.

Yes, that is true; you can *only* validate `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and certain types of `<input>` elements.

However, there is a workaround since the original `select` element is simply hidden...

1. You need to know the `name` or inspect your DOM to get the `name` attribute of your hidden `<select>` element.  Let's call it `mySelect`.
2. Allow the plugin to validate hidden elements by setting the `ignore` option to "nothing", like this:  `ignore: []`
3. Assuming you are trying to make the Selectric element "required", declare the `required` rule on your hidden `<select>` element.
4. Since the user is not interacting with the hidden `<select>`, there are no event triggers for the plugin to fire validation.  Write a custom handler that will trigger validation on the hidden element programmatically whenever its value changes.

   ```
   $('select[name="mySelect"]').on('change', function() { // fires when the value changes
       $(this).valid(); // trigger validation on hidden select
   });
   ```
5. Use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) of the plugin to place the error message in proximity to your dynamically generated Selectric element.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you :)